# Why doesn't mybatis3 support Set foreach?

Tags: java, mybatis, sqlmap

If parameterType is `java.util.Set`, or its implementation, doing foreach with this parameter throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
<select id="selectList" parameterType="java.util.HashSet" resultMap="someMap">
    SELECT key FROM tb_my_table
    WHERE value IN (
        <foreach collection="set" item="item" separator=",">
        #{item}
        </foreach>
    )
</select>
```

The cause inside mybatis3 is `CollectionWrapper` doesn't implement `get` method and just throws an exception.
I want to know whether it is intended design and the reason.

Comment: Would you please post the exception in detail?

Comment: @Forward All is `UnsupportedOperationException`. Take a look at CollectionWrapper of mybatis if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) states that using Sets is possible:

> You can pass **any Iterable object** (for example List, Set, etc.), as
>   well as any Map or Array object to foreach as collection parameter.

I could reproduce exception with Mybatis 3.2.7.

But it 's working fine with Mybatis 3.3.0.

Note that Expected name for single parameter is ***collection***:

```
<select id="selectList" parameterType="java.util.HashSet" resultMap="someMap">
    SELECT key FROM tb_my_table
    WHERE value IN (
        <foreach collection="collection" item="item" separator=",">
        #{item}
        </foreach>
    )
</select>
```

Comment: I tried mybatis 3.4.0 and checked it works. Empty implementation of CollectionWrapper isn't an issue. :)